# How do I determine the convergence or divergence of this?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=4}^\infty\frac{3+\cos n}{n^2+4}$$

I suppose you use Direct Comparison test, but I'm having trouble figuring out what to compare it to, and actually solving it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $$\sum_{n=4}^\infty\left|\frac{3+\cos(n)}{n^2+4}\right|\leq\sum_{n=4}^\infty\frac{4}{n^2+4}\leq\sum_{n=4}^\infty\frac{4}{n^2}.$$This shows the series is absolutely convergent, hence is convergent.

Comment: Can you explain how you did that?

Comment: @Mitchell, what about it is confusing? The idea was to find a bound on $\cos(n)$, and from the triangle inequality for real numbers, $|3+\cos(n)|\leq|3|+|\cos(n)|\leq 3+1=4$.

Comment: Oh! I understand now. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Mitchell: You are very welcome. Glad it helps.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $3+\cos n\in[2,4]$ for all $n$, and $\sum\frac1{n^2}$ is convergent.